# Create sub-Bitmap from a SoftwareBitmap in C#

Tags: c#, bitmap, uwp, hololens

I'm trying to do: https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/3263/zxing-unity-barcode-dll-issue

In fact, I have the same goal than the author of the post, but I don't agree with some of his conclusion, especially on the UWP usage. He choose to work with the Unity webcam, and I choose to work with the UWP framework which, IMO, work better with less FPS drops on AR applications.

But some of his approach is really interesting, especially his work with the quadrant. I'm trying to reproduce it with the UWP tech, and have some issues.

I already read every post on how to create sub-Bitmap, but every solution use the Bitmap library (System.Drawing) while the given format is a softwareBitmap. I have try to recreate a Bitmap with a raw array (I can obtain it from my softwareBitmap), but it seems to be crappy.

So, here's my question : Is there any way to re-create this quadrant concept on softwareBitmap model? No matter how, every solution is good (Bitmap, raw array, etc...)

Here is the code sample that I used for zxing and I will modified to integrate the quadrant scanning:

```
private void ColorFrameReader_FrameArrived(MediaFrameReader sender, MediaFrameArrivedEventArgs args)
{
    var mediaFrameReference = sender.TryAcquireLatestFrame();
    var videoMediaFrame = mediaFrameReference?.VideoMediaFrame;
    var softwareBitmap = videoMediaFrame?.SoftwareBitmap;

    if (softwareBitmap != null)
    {
        if (softwareBitmap.BitmapPixelFormat != Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8 ||
        softwareBitmap.BitmapAlphaMode != Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied)
        {
            softwareBitmap = SoftwareBitmap.Convert(softwareBitmap, BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);
          
        }
        softwareBitmap.CopyToBuffer(buffer);
        buffer2 = buffer.ToArray();
        
        result = DecodeBufferToQRCode(buffer2, softwareBitmap.PixelWidth, softwareBitmap.PixelHeight, BitmapFormat.BGRA32);          
        if(result != null)
        {
            print("Call send to zxing, result : " + result.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            
        }
    }
    mediaFrameReference.Dispose();
}
```

Thanks in advance

1st EDIT: I maybe have a solution based on row manipulation on the byte[] array that I can retrieve from the softwareBitmap, but it seems to be really heavy, in term of CPU and memory for the Hololens. So, I think a native solution (with Bitmap) will still be better if anyone have it.

The solution use this structure

```
//                                      3 | 4
List<byte[]> subImages; // the order is 1 | 2 in the list (so 1 is the inferior left corner of the pict)
```

with this kind of code

```
//Code used for picture splitting and decoding.
void imageProcess(byte[] image)
{   
    for(int i =0; i<= image.Length; i++)
    {
        if(i%resW < halfresW && i%resH < halfresH) //1
        {
           
        }else if (i % resW < halfresW && i % resH > halfresH)//3
        {

        }else if (i % resW > halfresW && i % resH < halfresH)//2
        {

        }
        else//4
        {

        }
    }

    //Then, process each
}
```

But at this point, I'm a quite lost: while my Bitmap use 32bpp(RGBA), should I multiply by 4 all my array stats (resolution and half resolution)?

Comment: Actually, editing the underlying byte data is usually a lot more efficient than using the managed functions...

Comment: Hi Nyerguds, I'm still trying on this way since I have no idea of how to do it in another way. I've just edit in order to show what I'm doing, but I'm still doubtfull on perf.

Comment: I'm not very well-acquainted with UWP tech, sorry :-\